# In github, how to merge one protected branch to another protected branch?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Let's assume a project that follows [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and let's say I have protected `develop`, `release-*` and `master` branches. How do I update one of these branches with another protected branch. This is my protection settings:

[image: Github Protection settings for both master and release-2.6.0 branch.]

e.g. If I try to merge `master` into `release-2.6.0` and the branch is out of date, then I'd see this dialogue asking me to `Update branch`:

[image: Branch update dialogue.]

And, of course, I can't click on `Update branch` because `master` is a protected branch and I can't just change it. So, I would get an error saying `Update branch attempt failed.`.

**Potential Solution**: One thing I guess I can do is first create a new (unprotected) branch from `master` and then try to merge this branch to `release-2.6.0`. However, I'm wondering if there's another elegant solution to follow [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) without using this circumvention.

Comment: Curious, why are you using squash and merge with git flow?

Comment: How about creating a pull request from one to the other?

Comment: @ElpieKay, please note the `Require branches to be up to date before merging` check. This check will try to update the current protected-branch so that it has all the latest code from the other protected-branch it's trying to merge to. And this can't be done, because protected branch can't be updated without a PR.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you recommend instead of `Squash and merge` and why?

Comment: Squash and merge edits the incoming commit history. This will require a push after a pull. If using the default pull it will first try a fast-forward, which will not require a push.